# How to repair ripped Ortlieb pannier

Tags: repair, panniers

I have an Ortlieb Back Roller pannier that has developed a rip about 6" (150mm) long along the lower rear inside corner – where the side/bottom joins the back (wheel side). It looks like this:

[image: Detail of rip in Ortlieb pannier]

In the photo I've pulled the rip open, if I let the pannier relax there is just a small slit, as if someone tried to slice the pannier open with a knife.

Is this something that can be reliably repaired?

Comment: Try your local shoe repair shop.

Comment: Another place that specialises in stuff like this is a saddlery (a horse shop if you like)  or a tent repairer.    They both tend to have big sewing machines for punching through layers of canvas and other materials.

Comment: Interesting ideas. Sounds like a sail maker would be another possibility. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the tear is in the worst place possible for a repair. :(

Comment: Also, an upholstery shop would be equipped to handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If its under the Ortlieb five year warrantee or you want it professionally done, send it back to them: https://www.ortlieb.com/en/service/garantie/

Locally, a local mountain shop, seamstress/tailor, sailmaker, upholstery shop, or shoe repair shop (tip of the hat to Daniel Hicks and dlu for the additions) might be able to do it for you. Whoever does the repair will need an industrial sewing machine -- or, more likely will have to handsew it because of its short length and awkward location. Prices will vary accordingly.

Otherwise, you could yourself sew it back together with [Kevlar thread](http://www.thethreadexchange.com/miva/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Category_Code=kevlar-thread-information) and a [large sewing needle or awl,](http://www.speedystitcher.com/speedy-stitcher-instructions/) with perhaps some ballistic nylon as backing. Since the tear is at a corner, you may have to dismantle the pack a bit. If this paragraph makes no sense, don't attempt it.

A quicker and much, much dirtier fix would be to use repair tape: either tent repair tape, resin-impregnated fiberglass or cloth tape (such as fiberfix), or make your own using epoxy resin and ballistic cloth. Or, as always, duct tape.

Comment: Any thoughts on how best to make the pannier waterproof again after the repair?

Comment: After you patched it, I would myself grind in sugru or shoe-goo into the seams -- additional spray on tent-seal at the very end would also help.

Comment: Completely OT for the current thread, but it's good to see you back on the review queues; we need the help! Sorry if it's due to your [shoulder](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42450/bicycle-designed-for-one-arm-usage). Keep us posted on progress.

Comment: @andy256 yeah, busted shoulder makes it hard to use the computer and the iPhone SE client doesn't have review tools. :(

Comment: @RoboKaren, Sorry to hear about the shoulder, good lead to Ortlieb, sent them e-mail over the weekend, got a prompt reply today.

Comment: That was the answer, pannier was replaced under warranty.

Comment: Ortlieb rocks. They were super good about getting me replacement parts for a bag as well. They're a five star company in my books. Well worth the price.