# Adult tandem trike conversion

Tags: axle, conversion, tandems, tricycle

I'd like to take my old tandem and make it a trike with dally tires and rims on the rear. Has anyone done it. Thanks

Comment: Do have a browse through the other questions on this site.  For example there are some useful answers at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/50058/19705   (not a direct dupe but similar.)

Comment: Did you want to have it remain a tandem? I don't know if any of the trike conversion kits could take the weight of two riders leaning over. The rear axle mounting bracket might snap.

Answer (score 3):

There is a front-end trike conversion system called the [Newton](http://www.roman-road.co.uk/conversions/tandem.htm) that has been used for tandems. I have no direct experience with it.

There are a number of rear-end trike conversion systems that are all similar in design: the [Trykit](http://www.trykit.com) and [Longstaff](http://www.longstaffcycles.com). I know that Longstaff has built tandem trikes from the ground up, although I don't know if their conversion kit is suitable for tandems.

You may note that these companies are all in the UK. Triking is much more established there.

Comment: Nice finds!  I wonder how bad it would be on a bike with the front and rear kits fitted - 4 wheels would have a terrible time keeping all the wheels on the road unless there was some significant frame flex.