# Created a unique approach to a tricycle, searching if others exist

Tags: tricycle

I read that wheels further apart from the center gives a more comfortable ride but I wanted something that fits through the door and on bike paths and alongside traffic.

I imagined just moving 1 wheel further apart from the center is better than none. It made a significant improvement in ride comfort and handling. If you offset too much then you get that sidecar type handling but this is just the right amount. The only downside is you have to steer more to turn left than right but you don't notice it.

The bolts bent over time but I have a better design for the next attempt.

I'm looking for information about the engineering concept I proposed with this design to find more data about it. Or ideas proposed with a similar concept. I tried every possible term in Google to find something to do with this with no luck.
[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, unfortunately the question is not that clear, and a discussion or asking for links is not suited to the QA format of this site. 
If you can rephrase the question and ask about advantages and disadvantages of design features, as long as its not too broad, the question may be able to remain open.

Comment: Clarifying - you're looking for help with tricycle adapter kits for an existing bike?    Have a read of this answer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/50058/19705   (and it still took me a good 10 minutes to find it, knowing it was there! )

Comment: @Criggie No not looking for adapters, I'm looking for information about the engineering concept I proposed to find more data about it.

Comment: @EricHuelin have a look a the link - it looks incredibly similar to your photo, except the rear axle is much beefier, seems to sit right at the dropouts, and isn't cantilevered off a couple of threadded rods.

Comment: @Criggie I want information about how I placed the wheels, the tracks, the geometry of the wheel positions. Look at the frame the left wheel is 10 inches from the center the right wheel is 16 inches from the center this is what I want by using the bolts to move the rear axle to one side.