# Modify a normal bike to suit my disability

Tags: road-bike, adaptive, disability

I am disabled in my right arm (Brachial Plexus) I would like to improve my comfort on my bike.I would also to know about the braking system fitted on one side.

Comment: Any competent bike shop should be able to move the right brake lever to the left side.  Of course, operating both brake levers with one hand would be a bit dicey.  There are schemes to operate two cables with one lever, but doing this would require a bit more skill than simply moving the lever, since there are several issues to consider.  As to overall comfort on the bike, that's an issue of "bike fit", something that a decent bike shop should be able to help you with.

Comment: you can read this question, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42450/bicycle-designed-for-one-arm-usage but are you asking specifically about a road bike, with drop handlebars? that's what you've tagged with

Comment: It may be helpful to know what you can do with your right arm and what type of bike you're looking to modify. As mentioned on that other link, would you consider a recumbent bike? Also, Google searching for "adaptive cycling" would find you sites and organizations that deal specifically with this. Last, the question isn't clear, but it sounds like you have a bike (upright bike?) and you can ride it with your injury, but you want to explore options to increase the comfort. Can you specify what's not comfortable?

Comment: Could you browse the linked question in Swifty's comment, and then see how your case differs.  If there are no real differences, then its a dupe (and you have valid answers already)   If your need is different, lets focus on those differences.

Comment: You've tagged this as [road-bike] which means a drop-bar racy bike.  Is that your intent or do you just mean a bike on the road ?   How's your balance?   What are the functions of your arm?  Is it folded up permanently or do you have some level of use ?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: All brake/shift-levers I know are asymmetric. The fit will be bad and you won't be able to shift when installed on the opposite side.

Comment: @Michael - If the right lever is badly asymmetric (which is sometimes but not always the case) then simply purchase a left brake lever.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Left brifters are for front derailleurs only. If OP needs rear derailleur shifting on the left side I think the best option would be indexed friction shifters.

Comment: @Michael - He didn't say anything about shifters, just brakes.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to control two brakes from a single lever?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/43344/23605)

Comment: Related (opposite hand): [can only use right hand to brake reliably, due to disability - safer/possible to modify bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/37357/23605)

Comment: Related: [Do skilled cyclists really “use the front brake alone probably 95% of the time”?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/10918/23605)

Answer (score 3):

If you using a flat handlebar, something like this would handle your braking needs:
[Problem Solvers Double Barrel](https://problemsolversbike.com/products/double-barrel-brake-lever) - it's a single brake lever that can actuate two brakes simultaneously.

Comment: For completeness, there's also a product that enables the user to pull both cable actuated brakes with one lever (or one brake with two levers, but not sure that helps  the OP). I have no idea what solution is available for hydraulic brakes, if those are what the OP wanted. https://problemsolversbike.com/products/brakes/12_-_8816o

Comment: Probably easier and safer to use a front brake only. If your need a rear brake it would be easiest with a coaster brake. However – I think – that’s only available for internal gear hubs.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer already covers cable-actuated brakes. To cover hydraulic brakes, Hope makes the Tech 3 Duo, a hydraulic brake with two split levers mounted on one side of the handlebar. It appears that you can pull each lever separately.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the three years since this post the road bike market has increasingly adopted hydraulic disc brakes. [Shimano has a good page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/information/news/smashing-limits-with-diy-adaptive-tech.html) on their website that addresses a single-hand, dual-lever solution using a mountain bike lever placed under the standard lever.

[This blog](https://cyclingwithadisability.wordpress.com/) shows two options for cable road bikes. Both options allow use of both brakes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You could improve your answer by quoting portions of the pages you reference in case they disappear someday.